# How to generate a file, of a given length, filled with random content, with Python?

Tags: python

I need to generate a file which is filled with random contents, and the size of the file should be of exactly size, no more, no less, like 1000 bytes. I have a small piece of C code that can finish this task, but I need to do it in Python.

Answer (score 9):

```
import os
with open('randomdata', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(os.urandom(1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import random
import string

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print "Usage: <output> <length>"
output = open(sys.argv[1], 'w')
length = int(sys.argv[2])

for i in xrange(length):
    output.write(random.choice(string.ascii_letters))
output.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the general case, please consider below function, which supports some buffering:

```
def mk_random_file(filename, size):
    max_chunksize = 100000
    written_bytes = 0
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            missing_bytes = size - written_bytes
            if missing_bytes > max_chunksize:
                f.write(os.urandom(max_chunksize))
                written_bytes += max_chunksize
            else:
                f.write(os.urandom(missing_bytes))
                break

mk_random_file("foofile", 1000)
```